# Lua unable to load VC++ dll

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, lua

I have compiled my *litertools* project as a .dll using the Visual Studio C/C++ toolchain and it correctly exports the `lua_openlitertools` function:

```
PS> dumpbin /exports .\bin\lib\litertools.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.22013.1

Dump of file .\bin\lib\litertools.dll    

  Section contains the following exports for litertools.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5439D35E time date stamp Sun Oct 12 12:03:26 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names  
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000227AD luaopen_litertools = @ILT+1960(_luaopen_litertools) 
  Summary

        1000 .data
        2000 .idata
        6000 .rdata
        2000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       44000 .text
       21000 .textbss
```

When I set configure `package.cpath` and then require the litertools dll by doing:

```
CMD> lua -e "package.cpath=\".\\bin\\lib\\?.dll\"; require(\"litertools\")"
```

I receive the following error

```
lua: error loading module 'litertools' from file '.\bin\lib\litertools.dll':
        The specified module could not be found.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        (command line):1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Looking into it, I debugged the call through require (loadlib.c), and got to here:

```
static void *ll_load (lua_State *L, const char *path, int seeglb) {
  HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryExA(path, NULL, LUA_LLE_FLAGS);
  (void)(seeglb);  /* not used: symbols are 'global' by default */
  if (lib == NULL) pusherror(L);
  return lib;
}
```

The call to `LoadLibraryExA` returns `NULL`. I am unsure as to *why* this happens, though I have compiled the same library using mingw-gcc and was able to require the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that dependency was not being found through using:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/
[image]

Move the unit tests into a separate project and corrected solution settings.